# git-diff Operation on CodeCommit repository after code has been pushed to obtain the diff file using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses, aws-codecommit

I have a AWS CodeCommit Repository that I want to perform a git-diff operation on and obtain the diff file containing changes made to all of the files in a push. I want to be able to send this file over using SES on AWS for approvals every-time something is pushed to the repo. Is there a way to achieve this using Lambdas? I don't see any way to get the diff file using any of the CodeCommit APIs.

Comment: Why not using pull request of CodeCommit to implement it?

Comment: There is [an AWS sample project](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codecommit-devops-model) to demonstrate the forced PR reviewing process for every commit.